# undefined reference to WinMain Error 1 in eclipse using mingw

Tags: eclipse

**** Build of configuration Debug for project testcase ****

```
make all 
Building target: testcase.exe
Invoking: MinGW C++ Linker
g++  -o"testcase.exe"  ./atest.o ./main.o  C:/cppunit/src/cppunit/.libs/libcppunit.a 
/mingw/lib/libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [testcase.exe] Error 1

undefined reference to `WinMain@16' : mingw/lib/libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:    
make: *** [testcase.exe] Error 1
```

but am using an cpp program. in cpp program which has main.cpp, atestcase.cpp and a.hpp  but it showing main.c:(.text+0xd2):

Can any one solve this problem .please can any one help me 
                                                           yours faithfully,
                                                           r.kranthikumar

Answer (score 5):

First, check you [did actually **save** your `main.c` file](http://www.peetm.com/blog/?p=278) (eclipse does not automatically save a source file)

Then, check if your makefile is autogenerated or if you can write it yourself, as in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg19017.html).

```
CXXFLAGS = -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0

OBJS =  main.o

LIBS =

TARGET =    say.exe

$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

all:    $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

Comment: See also http://yongshin.blogspot.com/2005/11/how-to-use-cdt-and-mingw-for-eclipse.html#c8263974258284865

Answer (score 2):

You're building a *Windows Application*, but you don't have a `WinMain` that is required by Windows applications.

Likely, you have a `main` instead. You'll need to either change your project settings (to something along the lines of "*Console Application*"), or use `WinMain` instead. You likely want the former.

Note, `WinMain` is not standard. This is just the Windows linkage requirement.

Answer (score 2):

(Is this a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040730/undefined-reference-to-winmain16-mingw-lib-libmingw32-amain-omain-c-coll)?)

You could keep your main but look up the options

```
--subsystem,windows -mwindows
```

in the documentation to your MinGW c++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you got main at least. I fixed mine by providing a main function. I didn't have one when I was compiling. I am on windows.. seems by default it is trying to look for winmain.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many solutions nothing worked for me.Then I re-created the project and moved the **.cpp** file to `projectname/src/` .

Tested in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If it is executable project then Make sure you should have a entry function main() in your project.