# Eclipse CDT Error: undefined reference to `WinMain@16' for a console app from C -> Empty Project - how to fix?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I am doing a Hello World C project in Eclipse CDT. I did 
File -> New -> C Project -> Executable -> Empty Project

When I compile it gives a link error that I think means that it thinks I am doing a Windows GUI program as it wants winmain@16 :

**CDT Build Console (HelloWorld)**

```
17:54:23 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project HelloWorld ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -o HelloWorld.exe HelloWorld.o 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
17:54:23 Build Finished (took 381ms)
```

My question - how to I change the project's options, if possible, to not want winmain@16 ?

I found that I can right click on the project name in the Project Explorer and select Properties off the menu, but I can't see anything for the executable type - console versus GUI.

Answer (score 0):

First (and best) guess: you saved your source before compiling? By default, Eclipse does not save the buffers before compiling, you have to explicitly state that in the options. Your compiler output should mention that it actually compiles the source code, looking like this:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used vor build
gcc -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\\main.c"
gcc -o HelloWorld.exe main.o
```

The message you provided did not contain that but perhaps you compiled the source in an earlier attempt.

I created an empty C project just like you, using MinGW 4.5.8 and gcc's linker accepted both ways to define the main functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char ** argv) { printf("Hello World!\n"); return 0; }
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) { 
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

If this did not help, maybe the Eclipse community mentioned something which inspires you at http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/153059 or http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/67342.

Similar issues: 
[eclipse + cdt + mingw + windows error "undefined reference to `WinMain@16'" on build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269112/eclipse-cdt-mingw-windows-error-undefined-reference-to-winmain16-on-b?rq=1), 
[undefined reference to WinMain Error 1 in eclipse using mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040730/undefined-reference-to-winmain-error-1-in-eclipse-using-mingw).